# How to I place a file into the default com.companyname.xamarinandroidapp directory for a Xamarin App?

Tags: file, xamarin

I created a sample Xamarin app using the wizard for Android App (Xamarin) in VS.Net 2019

Using an emulator I can see that on the SD CARD there is the following after I deploy my app.

SDCARD
Android
Data
com.companyname.xamarinandroidapp

I want to place a file in that com.companyname.xamarinandroidapp folder so when my app is installed the file is automatically there.

I have placed around with assets and built types for my files but nothing seems to make the file appear in this folder.

How do I do that? I want it to be there after install. I do not want to use code to write the file, but after the apk is installed it is there.

Chris

Comment: You can't do that.  Everything included in your app is inside of the app bundle.  You can, on app startup, copy a file from your bundle/assets to that folder.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that explains it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jason

I now know you can not do this and must manage the copying of files myself.

Cheers

Jason